# RecyclerView item get deforme as keyboard pop up

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I an activity I am using a dialog (which extend DialogFragment), Dialog contains a recycler view (w: match parent,h:200dp) and below recycler view an edit text and button, as soon as edit text is in focus and keyboard pops up the item in recycler view get deformed. dialog root view (card view) has w:match_parent h: wrap_content and list item root view (constraint layout) have w:match_parent   h:wrap_content

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BroIn.jpg)

Dialog :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="350dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_bold"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/label_add_remark"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/windowBackground" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_revisit_remarks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/revisit_rv_size"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:itemCount="6"
            tools:listitem="@layout/layout_remark_item" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_add_comment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_grey_border"
            android:minWidth="250dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rv_remarks">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_add_comment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="@string/add_your_comment"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:minHeight="40dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_color_light"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/button_submit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_bold"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:translationZ="0dp"
            app:cornerRadius="4dp"
            app:elevation="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

List Item:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/image_member_sample" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_dark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_profile_image"
        tools:text="BIna Antony Mari Kurian Paulose" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_comment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_dark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_name"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);